# Why does the first run of this simple file-read program takes 30 secs to execute?

Tags: c, file-io, eof, stdio

When I run the program for the first time, the file gets created. But it seems the while loop takes a long time to get over. Doesnt it get an EOF in the beginning of the file since the file is empty as of now?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    FILE *p;
    int b, a=0;b=0;
    p=fopen("text.txt", "a+");
    while((b=fscanf(p,"%d",&a)) != EOF)
        printf("%d\n",a);
    fseek(p, 0, SEEK_END);
    fprintf(p, " %d %d",1,6);
    fflush(p);
    fclose(p);
}
```

Comment: Why ` int b, a=0;b=0;` instead of `int a=0,b=0;`?

Comment: you don't need fseek in append mode

Comment: You could try profiling the program to see where it is spending most of its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure [fscanf returns 1](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *p;
    int b=0, a=0;
    p=fopen("text.txt", "a+");
    while((b=fscanf(p,"%d",&a)) == 1)
        printf("%d\n",a);
    // no need to seek, or flush
    fprintf(p, " %d %d",1,6);
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2499377, if you have non numeric data you can loop forever with fscanf because it will never skip that data.